# Can scripts be executed if they logged into log files by malicious user and the log file is opened in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, logging

I was doing an online course related to security. It said 'Do not log unsanitized user input'

They warned that an attacker might put a script inside it, which might get triggered if you open the log file in browser. I am trying to reproduce it but I can't seem to.

Does anyone have idea about it ?

say I put "alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");" in my log file. But when I open it in browser, I see it as plain text only. No alert is shown

Comment: Well if something renders it has html it would execute. It is an edge case.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it in script tags:

```
<script>alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");</script>
```

Also, if you have PHP running, it might parse the log file, then you can exploit like this:

```
<?php echo "\nHi";
```

Even if this doesn't work, if you have code including other files, the attacker may trick your file inclusion to include and execute the log file.
Like this (really unusual and bad code):

```
<?php include 'lib/'.$_GET['module'];
```